# Randomly Assign an Image's Alt Text Based on Data From Post

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, post-thumbnails, post-meta

I would like randomly assign an image an alt text based on taxonomy entered by the user on a post that the image is attached if there is no alt text entered.

For example, on a post that has an image, I would like to randomly assign something like: "Used Camping Trailer in North Carolina." Where the **USED** and **CAMPING TRAILER** would be pulled from data entered on the post.

I have this working on page load,  but obviously, this would be bad SEO because it's going to change on every page load. Therefore is there a way to do it and it be entered into the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the image alt text when the image is saved.  Hook onto the save_post action, check if any of the attached images don't have alt text, and if not then generate the alt text you want and save it with:

```
update_post_meta( $attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', 'this is the alt text' );
```